# printing time to std::ostream

Tags: c++, string, time, iostream, cout

I have just started reading a C++ textbook and I am having trouble solving one of the coding problems at the end of the chapter. Here is the question:

Write a program that asks the user to enter an hour value and a minute value. The
main() function should then pass these two values to a type void function that displays
the two values in the format shown in the following sample run:

Enter the number of hours: 9
Enter the number of minutes: 28
Time: 9:28

my code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void time(int h, int m);

int main()
{
    int hour, min;

    cout << "enter the number of hours: ";
    cin >> hour;
    cout << "enter the number of minutes: ";
    cin >> min;

    string temp = time(hour, min);

    cout << temp;

    return 0;
}

void time(int h, int m)
{
    string clock;
    clock =
}
```

What do I do now inside the `time(n, m)` function?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: please don't add both printfs and couts.  stick to one, preferably couts in c++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include `<iomanip>` and set [field width](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) and [fill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setfill/) so that times like `9:01` are printed properly. And since the function `time` should just print the time, building and returning a `std::string` can be omitted. Just print these values:

```
void time(int hour, int min)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Time: " << hour << ':' << setfill('0') << setw (2) << min << endl;
}
```

Also note that writing `using namespace std;` at the beginning of your files is considered bad practice since it causes some of user-defined names (of types, functions, etc.) to become ambiguous. If you want to avoid exhausting prefixing with `std::`, use `using namespace std;` within small scopes so that other functions and other files are not affected.

Comment: what about a 2 digit minute?  e.g. 9:01 would be 9:1

Answer (score 1):

The question requests "a type void function that displays the two values in the format shown" so the simplest and most correct (because it matches what was asked) solution is:

```
void time(int h, int m)
{
  cout << "Time: " << h << ":" << m << endl;
}
```

Your main() function then needs to do nothing but...

```
  // ... prompt for values as before, then:

  time(hour, min);

  return 0;
}
```

and then return.

Answer (score 0):

First time() should return a std::string. To format the string inside time() you could use std::ostringstream (header sstream).

Eg:

```
std::string time(int hour, int minutes)
{
   std::ostringstream oss;
   oss << hour << ":" << minutes;
   return oss.str();
}
```

Edit:
Of course, you could also print hour and minutes directly inside the time(..) function. Or you could pass the time(..) function also a stream argument to let time(..) print it out on that stream.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in main is assuming that `time` is a `string` method, the question states `void`. Your code should be:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
void time(int h, int m); 

int main() 
{ 
    int hour, min; 

    cout << "enter the number of hours: "; 
    cin >> hour; 
    cout << "enter the number of minutes: "; 
    cin >> min; 

    // Now pass to your time method.
    time(hour, min); 

    return 0; 
} 

void time(int h, int m)     
{     
    cout << "Time: " << h << ':' << m << endl;     
}
```

and Bob is someone's uncle.